# many to one field self relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i used a `self` relationship inside model with `foreignkey` , purpose was to make a replyable comment , but idk how to use it in templates,
i mean whats different between 3 `ManyToOne` relationships i used in template , how can i know form send reply or comment?
model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    #comments model
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),related_name='users',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True,related_name='reply',on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = 'Comments'
        ordering = ['date']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.test[:50]
```

template:

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button value="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    {% for comment in object.comments.all %}
        <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
        {% for reply in object.reply.all %}
            <p>{{ reply.text }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <form method='post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button value="submit">reply</button>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

can you a little explain how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using a recursive solution in your code using [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) template tag, like this:

First define a template which will render the comment:

```
<!-- comments.html -->
{% for comment in comments %}
    <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
    <form method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button value="submit">reply</button>
    </form>
    {% if comment.reply.exists %}
        <ul>
            {% include "comments.html" with comments=comment.reply.all %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then include it in the original template:

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button value="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
   {% include "comments.html" with comments=object.comments_only %}
</div>
```

Finally, only send the Comments which does not have parents,like this:

```
class Post(...):
   ...
   def comments_only(self):
      return self.comments.filter(parent__isnull=True)
```

Comment: yeah thanks it's neat ,mine was mess (if it was correct) , but just to understand what im doing ,when i send a comment to database it is related to post right? and if i send a reply it is related to comment? so all i needed was creating a column for reply?

Comment: also ``` {% include "comments.html" with comments=comment.reply.all %}``` here why did you use ```comments ``` and this only show replies related to that comment ive just never used it

Comment: i just used a common variable to make recursive call consistent

Comment: I understand your one concern, here I added a new method (in updated answer) to send only the comments which does not have any parent.

Comment: thank you , ill try to study more on your methods

Comment: if i want to see a comments reply, or a reply's replies how can i check it in shell or template(couldnt find any docs)

Comment: for comments reply: print(comment_object.reply.all()), reply of reply [reply.reply.all() for reply in comment_object.reply.all()].